# How to force closing a connection in HTTPUrlConnection and make sure a new connection is open with openConnection()

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I wrote a simple HTTP client to send rest request to a server. Several times I've had an `IllegalStateException: Already connected` and got stuck with that. Moreover I'm using the same URL with different method (`POST` and `GET`) and they seem to conflict: when I make a request it opens the previous connection with the same method, and I can't find how to change it.

How can I be sure that the connection is really disconnected after the request and that `openConnection()` opens a new connection?

**edit**
I tried adding `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` before `HttpURLConnection conn = null;`, but I still get the error.

```
public class RestClient {


    final static public int HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
    final static public int HTTP_200_OK = 200;

    static public Map<String, Object> post(String urlStr, NameValuePair[] data, boolean hasInput){

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();            

            if(hasInput) conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            if(data != null){

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getQuery(data));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();

            if(status==HTTP_200_OK) is = conn.getInputStream();
            else is = conn.getErrorStream();    

            response.put("response_code", conn.getResponseCode());

            response.put("response_content", readIt(is));

            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("response_code", -1);
            response.put("response_content", e.getMessage());
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("response_code", -1);
            response.put("response_content", e.getMessage());
            return response;
        }
        finally {

            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            if(conn!=null) conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fast workaround:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

But I'm not sure whether this really solves your problem. I could imagine that the `IllegalStateException` is caused by the wrong order of method calls to the connection object.

Setting this property can degrade performance.